# when try to pass data to form a JSON it will take the only one value not all the one?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    if (location?.length == 1 ) {
      //lets say location is 'location1'
      autoDropdown('location', location[0])
    }

    if (country.length == 1) {
      //lets say country is 'country1'
      autoDropdown('country', country[0])
    }
  }, [country, location])



const autoDropdown= (name, value) => {
    setFormValue({
      ...form,
      [name]: value,
    })
  }
```

Output is: `{location: 'location1'}`

Expected output: `{location:'location1', country: 'country1'}`

Why it didn't get the country?

Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: `setFormValue`? I don't see it.

Comment: It's setForm, sry typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `setFormValue` it takes the current value of `form` and adds or replaces one property on the object stored in it as determined by the value of `form`.

When you call `setFormValue` you trigger an update and the component function is called again to see if a rerender is needed. When it gets called again, `form` has the new value you just set.

Since you are calling `autoDropdown` twice **in sequence** there isn't a re-render between the two calls, so `form` **hasn't been updated**.

The second time you call `autoDropdown` it runs `...form` with the **same** value. this doesn't include the data you added or changed from the first call to `autoDropdown` so that change is lost.

---

I've never used this feature, but I think you can use a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to solve your problem:

```
const autoDropdown= (name, value) => {
    setFormValue(latestForm => ({
      ...latestForm,
      [name]: value,
    }))
  }
```